# Removing Project Symbol Search button

Tags: delphi, ide

Is it possible to remove or disable the Project Symbol Search button from the Dephi (10.2) editor. It is the magnifying glass on the far right in the image below.

[image: Delphi editor toolbar]

It is a nuisance to me because I keep pressing it instead of the dropdown arrow on the Methods combo box next to it (because my hand co-ordination is poor) and it freezes the IDE for 20-30 seconds.

Comment: As an alternative for the navigation toolbar you might want to have a look at the [MMX CodeExplorer](https://www.mmx-delphi.de/) plugin though actually it is a very powerful refactoring tool.

Comment: You could use one of the Delphi IDE explorer tools and write a plugin that simply hides that particular control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Tools > Options > Editor Options > Display` there is only an option to turn off the hole toolbar ("navigation toolbar").

The toolbar is not even mentioned in the [docs for the options dialog](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Display)!

But at least you can find information about it [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Code_Editor#Navigation_Toolbar) and [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Using_the_Navigation_Toolbar) in the docs.

Comment: That's great thanks. And I've installed MMX as well.